# Indian seeking to visit Dubai and then Muscat... How to do it?

Tags: transportation, dubai, uae, oman, muscat

I wish to travel to Dubai and stay in Dubai for about two day and then travel to Muscat for may be another 3 days or so and then travel back to India ?

I have a visa to Dubai and a relative will get me a visit to Muscat so need advice on actually how to travel ?

Will be travelling by flight from India to Dubai. need to know travel by Bus or Air is recommended for travel in between Dubai and Muscat ?  Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: This is a broad question to answer. It's 6 hour drive to Muscat, and there will be plenty of flights too (you are in Dubai!!). There seems to be no direct public transport, but I don't think it's impossible to to manage public transport in segments. Is your question about immigration and visa?(because you tagged it)

Answer (score 1):

To get from Dubai to Muscat, you have any number of choices:

1. Flights (there are more than 16 flights a day between Dubai and Muscat).
2. You can drive there by car (you'll need special insurance to cross the border, and if renting, you'll need extra coverage); it takes between 5:30 and 6 hours.
3. The [Oman National Transport Company](http://www.ontcoman.com/) runs a bus service as well; the buses run 7:30, 3:30 and 4:30 from Dubai. There is also Comfort Line that you can contact who also run bus services. You can find their offices in Deira.